# Swift gdc use a lot of memory

Tags: swift

On MacOs (swift 2.1).
This code use more then 7Gb memory and I can't clean it.
How I can clean memory?
If I put `usleep(10)` before `dispatch_async(queue!)` then memory used only 1Gb

```
import Foundation
import Darwin

class Thread: NSObject
{
    private var thread: NSThread?
    private var callback: (Void -> Void)?

    init(_ callback : Void -> Void) {
        super.init()
        self.callback = callback

        self.thread = NSThread(target: self, selector: "invoke", object: nil);
        thread?.start();
    }

    func invoke() {
        self.callback?()

        // Discard callback and timer.
        self.callback = nil
        self.thread = nil
    }
}

var queue:dispatch_queue_t? = dispatch_queue_create("com.test", nil);

for i in 0...20 {
    Thread(){
        for j in 0...100000 {
            dispatch_async(queue!) {

            }
        }
    }
}

sleep(20)
```

Comment: The queue will have 2 million blocks scheduled, that does not sound very performant... What are trying to do here?

Comment: I know it, but after finished loop, memory not cleared. I need it for highload project.